# Can't find the C room in the "message move search window"

Tags: bug, chat

Several days ago I tried moving a question about C from a C# room to the [C](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/54304/c) room, but this failed for two reasons:

1. First, in order for autocomplete to happen, you need to type in several characters, even waiting long enough won't trigger it. I had to work around this by adding spaces.
2. The room didn't appear in the search results because they only seem to show 10 most recently active rooms, without the ability to search for check the next rooms. Of course, the C room didn't appear, even though it was a perfect match.

[image: interactive problem description]

Comment: And I tried also with the room number (54304) => well, doesn't work either

Comment: You can type `C stands`.... as in `C stands for control` :D

Comment: The search also seems to support bracketed *`[tags]`*

Comment: @AnttiHaapala Nice! Alternatively I could post a message in the C room and in the meantime quickly find the C room :)

Comment: So, after typing *the complete name* of the room to which you want to move the post ("C"), typing <enter> does not perform the move?  Or didn't you try that?  I can understand being surprised because you're used to getting autocompletion, but there's no inherent reason why you should need to autocomplete a tag name that's already complete.

Comment: @JohnBollinger **I** did try that **now**, and no, it doesn't work.

Comment: @JohnBollinger Pressing enter does the search, but it won't show the C room because of point 2 (see question)

Comment: Where are the moving free-hand circles?